# Convert XML into another XML via XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML file as following and I want to convert it into another XML file.

```
<body>
  <outline text="A">
    <outline text="Abelson, Harold" author="Harold Abelson" title="Struktur und Interpretation von Computerprogrammen. Eine Informatik-Einführung" publisher="Springer Verlag" isbn="3540520430" year="1991"/>
    <outline text="Abrahams, Paul W." author="Paul W. Abrahams" title="Tex for the Impatient" publisher="Addison-Wesley Pub Co" isbn="0201513757" year="2000"/>
  </outline>
  <outline text="B">
    <outline text="Bach, Fred" author="Fred Bach" title="UNIX Handbuch zur Programmentwicklung" publisher="Hanser Fachbuchverlag" isbn="3446151036"/>
    <outline text="Bach, Maurice J." author="Maurice J. Bach" title="Design of the UNIX Operating System" publisher="Prentice Hall PTR" isbn="0132017997" year="1986"/>
  </outline>
</body>
```

Here is XML format that I want to convert to

```
<list>
    <books text="A">
        <book>
            <text>Abelson, Harold</text>
            <author>Harold Abelson</author>
            <title>Struktur und Interpretation von Computerprogrammen. Eine
                Informatik-Einführung</title>
            <publisher>Springer Verlag</publisher>
            <isbn>3540520430</isbn>
            <year>1991</year>
        </book>
        <book>
            <text>Abrahams, Paul W.</text>
            <author>Paul W. Abrahams</author>
            <title>Tex for the Impatient</title>
            <publisher>Addison-Wesley Pub Co</publisher>
            <isbn>0201513757</isbn>
            <year>2000</year>
        </book>

    </books>
    <books text="B">
        <book>
            <text>Bach, Fred</text>
            <author>Fred Bach</author>
            <title>UNIX Handbuch zur Programmentwicklung</title>
            <publisher>Hanser Fachbuchverlag</publisher>
            <isbn>3446151036</isbn>
            <year />
        </book>
```

Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="body">
        <list> <xsl:apply-templates select="outline"/> </list>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="outline">
    <books text= "{@text}">
        <book><xsl:apply-templates select="outline"/> 
        <text><xsl:value-of select="@text" /></text>
        <author><xsl:value-of select="@author" /></author>
        <title><xsl:value-of select="@title" /></title>
        <publisher><xsl:value-of select="@publisher" /></publisher>
        <isbn><xsl:value-of select="@isbn" /></isbn>
        <year><xsl:value-of select="@year" /></year>
        </book>
    </books>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and here is the output of my code.

```
<list>
    <books text="A">
        <book>
            <books text="Abelson, Harold">
                <book>
                    <text>Abelson, Harold</text>
                    <author>Harold Abelson</author>
                    <title>Struktur und Interpretation von Computerprogrammen. Eine
                        Informatik-Einführung</title>
                    <publisher>Springer Verlag</publisher>
                    <isbn>3540520430</isbn>
                    <year>1991</year>
                </book>
            </books>
```

There are two extra elements in my output

```
<books text="Abelson, Harold">
                <book>
```

as my knowledge this maybe caused by this line of code. I tried few different way, but didn't work

```
<xsl:template match="outline">
        <books text= "{@text}">
```

Additional Question:
If the original XML files contains title. How to eliminate the head and title. My current code produce "tmp" in the new XML file.

```
<opml version="1.0">
  <head>
    <title>tmp</title>
    <expansionState></expansionState>
  </head>
  <body>
      <outline text="A">
      <outline text="Abelson, Harold" author="H
```

Comment: I suggest to use Stylus Studio tool to achieve this.[**LINK**](http://www.stylusstudio.com/)

Comment: Why? This is not editor's problem. or it provides solution?

Comment: Michael, you may be interested in a much shorter solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right track, but you need two `outline` templates - one for the top level `outline`s, and one for the child `outlines`.

Please replace your `outline` template with these three:

```
  <xsl:template match="head" />

  <xsl:template match="outline">
    <books text="{@text}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="outline" />
    </books>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="outline/outline">
    <book>
      <text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@text" />
      </text>
      <author>
        <xsl:value-of select="@author" />
      </author>
      <title>
        <xsl:value-of select="@title" />
      </title>
      <publisher>
        <xsl:value-of select="@publisher" />
      </publisher>
      <isbn>
        <xsl:value-of select="@isbn" />
      </isbn>
      <year>
        <xsl:value-of select="@year" />
      </year>
    </book>
  </xsl:template>
```

And if it can be safely assumed that the names of the attributes of the source document will match the names of the elements in the output document, you can replace that second template with these two shorter, more streamlined ones:

```
  <xsl:template match="outline/outline">
    <book>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@text" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@author" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@title" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@publisher" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@isbn" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@year" />
    </book>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="outline/outline/@*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
       <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Or browse the XSLT questions here on SO. There's a lot of great stuff here. You're welcome. :)

Comment: Thanks, Do you know how to eliminate the html head in the XML?

Comment: Yes, you can just add `<xsl:template match="head" />` to the XSLT.  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a slightly more-push oriented solution that doesn't rely quite as much on manually pulling elements from the source XML into the result XML. In particular, notice the last template.

**When this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <list>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </list>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="outline[outline]">
    <books text="{@text}">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </books>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="outline[not(*)]">
    <book>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
    </book>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="outline[not(*)]/@*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...is applied against the provided source XML:**

```
<body>
  <outline text="A">
    <outline text="Abelson, Harold" author="Harold Abelson" title="Struktur und Interpretation von Computerprogrammen. Eine Informatik-Einführung" publisher="Springer Verlag" isbn="3540520430" year="1991"/>
    <outline text="Abrahams, Paul W." author="Paul W. Abrahams" title="Tex for the Impatient" publisher="Addison-Wesley Pub Co" isbn="0201513757" year="2000"/>
  </outline>
  <outline text="B">
    <outline text="Bach, Fred" author="Fred Bach" title="UNIX Handbuch zur Programmentwicklung" publisher="Hanser Fachbuchverlag" isbn="3446151036"/>
    <outline text="Bach, Maurice J." author="Maurice J. Bach" title="Design of the UNIX Operating System" publisher="Prentice Hall PTR" isbn="0132017997" year="1986"/>
  </outline>
</body>
```

**...the wanted result is produced:**

```
<list>
  <books text="A">
    <book>
      <text>Abelson, Harold</text>
      <author>Harold Abelson</author>
      <title>Struktur und Interpretation von Computerprogrammen.
        Eine Informatik-Einführung</title>
      <publisher>Springer Verlag</publisher>
      <isbn>3540520430</isbn>
      <year>1991</year>
    </book>
    <book>
      <text>Abrahams, Paul W.</text>
      <author>Paul W. Abrahams</author>
      <title>Tex for the Impatient</title>
      <publisher>Addison-Wesley Pub Co</publisher>
      <isbn>0201513757</isbn>
      <year>2000</year>
    </book>
  </books>
  <books text="B">
    <book>
      <text>Bach, Fred</text>
      <author>Fred Bach</author>
      <title>UNIX Handbuch zur Programmentwicklung</title>
      <publisher>Hanser Fachbuchverlag</publisher>
      <isbn>3446151036</isbn>
    </book>
    <book>
      <text>Bach, Maurice J.</text>
      <author>Maurice J. Bach</author>
      <title>Design of the UNIX Operating System</title>
      <publisher>Prentice Hall PTR</publisher>
      <isbn>0132017997</isbn>
      <year>1986</year>
    </book>
  </books>
</list>
```

Answer (score 3):

**A much shorter, complete solution:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*"><list><xsl:apply-templates/></list></xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="outline">
    <books text="{@text}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </books>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="outline/outline">
    <book><xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/></book>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="outline/outline/@*">
      <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<body>
  <outline text="A">
    <outline text="Abelson, Harold" author="Harold Abelson" title="Struktur und Interpretation von Computerprogrammen. Eine Informatik-Einführung" publisher="Springer Verlag" isbn="3540520430" year="1991"/>
    <outline text="Abrahams, Paul W." author="Paul W. Abrahams" title="Tex for the Impatient" publisher="Addison-Wesley Pub Co" isbn="0201513757" year="2000"/>
  </outline>
  <outline text="B">
    <outline text="Bach, Fred" author="Fred Bach" title="UNIX Handbuch zur Programmentwicklung" publisher="Hanser Fachbuchverlag" isbn="3446151036"/>
    <outline text="Bach, Maurice J." author="Maurice J. Bach" title="Design of the UNIX Operating System" publisher="Prentice Hall PTR" isbn="0132017997" year="1986"/>
  </outline>
</body>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<list>
 <books text="A">
   <book>
      <text>Abelson, Harold</text>
      <author>Harold Abelson</author>
      <title>Struktur und Interpretation von Computerprogrammen. Eine Informatik-Einführung</title>
      <publisher>Springer Verlag</publisher>
      <isbn>3540520430</isbn>
      <year>1991</year>
   </book>
   <book>
      <text>Abrahams, Paul W.</text>
      <author>Paul W. Abrahams</author>
      <title>Tex for the Impatient</title>
      <publisher>Addison-Wesley Pub Co</publisher>
      <isbn>0201513757</isbn>
      <year>2000</year>
   </book>
 </books>
 <books text="B">
   <book>
      <text>Bach, Fred</text>
      <author>Fred Bach</author>
      <title>UNIX Handbuch zur Programmentwicklung</title>
      <publisher>Hanser Fachbuchverlag</publisher>
      <isbn>3446151036</isbn>
   </book>
   <book>
      <text>Bach, Maurice J.</text>
      <author>Maurice J. Bach</author>
      <title>Design of the UNIX Operating System</title>
      <publisher>Prentice Hall PTR</publisher>
      <isbn>0132017997</isbn>
      <year>1986</year>
   </book>
 </books>
<list>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Proper use of templates and match patterns.
2. Proper use of **[`<xsl:element>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Creating-Elements-with-xsl%3aelement)**

---

**II. In case a specific order of the generated elements is needed (as the order of the source attributes cannot be guaranteed), use this slight modification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*"><list><xsl:apply-templates/></list></xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="outline">
    <books text="{@text}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </books>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="outline/outline">
    <book>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*">
        <xsl:sort data-type="number" select=
          string-length(substring-before('text|author|title|publisher|isbn|year',name()))"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates></book>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="outline/outline/@*">
      <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your output is missing the outer `<list>` element and your approach assumes that the attributes will always be in the same order, which can be a dangerous assumption.

Comment: @JLRishe, I am curious to know: Where do I assume any ordering of attributes?

Comment: Right here: `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>`. Try swapping the order of the `text` and `author` attributes in the source XML, and the output XML will have the `author` element before the `text` element. And while the order of attributes cannot be required by a schema, the order of elements quite often is.

Comment: @JLRishe, Oh, I see. I added a "Part II" that performs the processing in the wanted order. Only two lines added. :)

Comment: Clever trick. I'll definitely make a mental note of that technique.